# boost::process::env broken on ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

The following C++ program:

```
#include <boost/process/env.hpp>

int main() {}
```

Won't compile:

```
$ g++ test.cc

In file included from test.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/process/env.hpp:107:19: error: ‘is_wchar_t’ is not a class template
 template<> struct is_wchar_t<env_set<wchar_t>>           : std::true_type {};
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04 with gcc 8.3.0 and libboost1.67-dev.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also broken on RHEL

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is to include the file that defines the is_wchar_t template:

```
#include <boost/process/detail/traits/wchar_t.hpp>
```

Comment: Still broken in 2022.  Sheesh.

Comment: The fix was [merged](https://github.com/boostorg/process/pull/245), expected to appear in Boost 1.80.